# Ctrl-F is not working in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, shortcut

I was just issued a new workstation, and had SharePoint Designer 2013 installed. Ctrl-F is supposed to open the Find dialog, it does nothing. Is there a specific option setting I am overlooking? I don't remember having to do this for SharePoint Designer anywhere else I have used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a reboot of my workstation enabled the Ctrl-F functionality. It had not been rebooted since the installation of the application.